# Calling cancellationToken.Cancel() in Dispose of Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dispose, cancellation-token

I have controller, where I create a Cancellation Token in the constructor and use it in a long running await task (). Does disposing the Cancellation token in Controller.Dispose() causes the long running task to cancel?

```
public class SomeController : BaseInternalController
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public MyController()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(SomeData data)
    {
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            await longRunningTask(item, cancellationTokenSource.token);
        }

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: The controller won't be disposed until the task returned by `Post` completes - i.e., after the `longRunningTask` is complete.

Comment: You can add a CancellationToken to your Post method. This will be filled in by the framework and set to cancelled state if the client disconnects. This way the client can decide when he no longer wants to wait.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does disposing the Cancellation token in Controller.Dispose() causes
>   the long running task to cancel?

Depends on how your `longRunningTask` was implemented.
In this method you should explicitly check whether the cancellation is requested:

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

After invoking of this method your task will be cancelled.

### Cancellation example

If in the following example the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` would not be invoked, the task would be run forever:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, cts.Token);
```

You can learn more about cancellation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Note that after setting the `cancellationTokenSource` to `null`, you can get `NullReferenceException` in your `foreach` loop. I would suggest to copy your token into a local variable:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(SomeData data)
{
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        await longRunningTask(item, token);
    }
}
```